# AWS EC2 Policy - Describe own properties

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

When creating AWS Policies, is there a way to create a policy that, when assigned to an EC2 Instance, allows querying its own tags without granting access to other instances tags?

Is there a sense of 'self' or 'own'? Some magic character like '*'?

Comment: can you filter for said AMI? `--filter "resource-id=ami-1a2b3c4d"`

Comment: I think the AMI is irrelevant in this case.